# how I can insert and update (edit) latitude and long using (form.py) python Django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, google-maps

I want to insert latitude and long using python Django. I use code but does not work when click on the button it shows null in DB.

models.py

```
class UserLocation(models.Model):
    map_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    map_u_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=7, null=False, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=7, null=False, blank=True)
```

view.py

```
def save_location(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.POST

        latitude = form.get('latitude')
        longitude = form.get('longitude')
        user_id = request.session['user_id']


        insert_data = UserLocation.objects.create(                latitude=latitude,longitude=longitude,

                                                  )
        if insert_data:

            json_data = {'msg': "Insert data successfully", 'state_val': 1}
            return JsonResponse(json_data)
        else:
            json_data = {'msg': "Data not saved", 'state_val': 2}
            return JsonResponse(json_data)
    else:
        return render(request, 'map_1.html')
```

how I can do an update (edit) for latitude and long using (form.py) python Django?

Comment: Please consider adding `django` tag to your question to make it easier to find for user with experience in it

Comment: How is the code you initially posted related to what you added?

Comment: The fields are defined with `null=False` and you have NULL values in the database? Did you add  `null=False`  after you created the database and forgot to do a migration? Or do you look at the wrong database?

Comment: I did migration with null= true and null= false. still not insert lat and log values in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
# Import your UserLocation model
from .models import UserLocation

# Create your forms here
class UserLocationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserLocation
        fields = ('latitude', 'longitude')
```

## In views.py

```
from .forms import UserLocationForm

def save_location(request):
    form = UserLocationForm()
    context = {}
    context['form'] = form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLocationForm(request.POST)
        user_id = request.session['user_id']
        if form.is_valid():
            insert_data = form.save()
            if insert_data:
                json_data = {'msg': "Insert data successfully", 'state_val': 1}
                return JsonResponse(json_data)
            else:
                json_data = {'msg': "Data not saved", 'state_val': 2}
                return JsonResponse(json_data)
        else:
            # Update form in context dictionary
            context['form'] = form
            # Re-render page with prefilled data
            return render(request, 'map_1.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'map_1.html', context)
```

## In template

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

## For Updating location

## In views.py

```
def update_location(request, location_id):
    try:
        # Get location from db for location_id
        location = UserLocation.objects.get(id=location_id)
    except UserLocation.DoesNotExist:
        return # redirect user back as the location id is invalid
    # Populate the form with data of requested instance
    form = UserLocationForm(instance=location)
    context = {}
    context['form'] = form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLocationForm(request.POST)
        user_id = request.session['user_id']
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return # Redirect user to somewhere
        # When the posted data is invalid
        else:
            # Update form in context dictionary
            context['form'] = form
            # Re-render page with prefilled data
            return render(request, 'update_location.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'update_location.html', context)
```

## In update_location.html

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

## In urls.py

```
path('update_location/<int:location_id>/', views.update_location, name="update-location"),
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. is there a way that I can get the data from DB and edit them then insert them again. I Know by using models.py and view.py. How I can get data from form.py ....

Comment: Yes of course! you mean update something in database using views and a form.

Comment: Yes, after submitting data, how I can get the data visible when clicking on the update button and it shows all data in DB in text fields then I can change data and submit it again in the same row in DB.